# I got a wrong background when I set the margin property to zero in the body element

Tags: html, css

I just study HTML&CSS several days ago,through watching videos and reading relevant tutorials in W3C.So maybe I miss some important points.

I want to make a gradient background animation by css.And following is my css and  html code:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
 background: linear-gradient(132deg,#ec5218,#1665c1);
 background-size: 400% 400%;
 animation: BackgroundGradient 30s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes BackgroundGradient{
 0%{background-position: 0% 50%;}
 50%{background-position: 100% 50%;}
 100%{background-position: 0% 50%;}
}

h1{
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
       <title>Gradiendt Background</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
  </head> 

  <body>
       <h1>There is a gradient background.</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run the code,I get a white background rather than a linear-gradient background.But if I set the background property to a single color in the body element,like blue,it does works.Or I set the margin property to a non-zero value,like 1px,I would get the right linear-gradient background I want.So maybe I really miss sth.

Could anyone give me some tips?I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You defined for `h1` element `position:absolute;` property, so the element is removed completely from the normal flow of the document.

*and also,*

you set for `body` a `margin:0` this causes `body` get height equal 0 so don't show background.(default margin for body is 8px).

*For fix it define `min-height` for `body`:*

**Fix it :**

```
   body {
       min-height: 1px;
       margin:0;
       //more code...
    }
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  min-height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(132deg,#ec5218,#1665c1);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: BackgroundGradient 30s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes BackgroundGradient{
  0%{background-position: 0% 50%;}
  50%{background-position: 100% 50%;}
  100%{background-position: 0% 50%;}
}

h1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
  <body>
       <h1>There is a gradient background.</h1>
  </body>
```

Comment: At first,thanks for your answer which had solved my problem.But maybe there is one place strange in your explanation.The linear-gradient bg is not a **background-color** value but a **background-image** value.Even if **body** has no height,the **color** can be still reflected out.

Answer (score 1):

`Body` has no height since child is off the flow via `position:absolute`., so 400% of no height gives a background of 0 height when you try to resize it.

You can either set safely a `min-height:100vh` to `body`  , to cover the viewport and it will show even if a background is set to HTML.

Else , any `min-height` value will be enough to cover the viewport if `html` has no background define.

**See** https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds to understand the behavior of `background` when `html` and/or `body` is involved.

> **3.11.2. The Canvas Background and the HTML  Element**
>
> For documents whose root element is an HTML HTML element [HTML401] or an XHTML html element [XHTML11]: if the computed value of ‘background-image’ on the root element is ‘none’ and its ‘background-color’ is ‘transparent’, user agents must instead propagate the computed values of the background properties from that element's first HTML BODY or XHTML body child element. The used values of that BODY element's background properties are their initial values, and the propagated values are treated as if they were specified on the root element. It is recommended that authors of HTML documents specify the canvas background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
 background: linear-gradient(132deg,#ec5218,#1665c1);
 background-size: 400% 400%;
 animation: BackgroundGradient 30s ease infinite;
  min-height:100vh;
}

@keyframes BackgroundGradient{
 0%{background-position: 0% 50%;}
 50%{background-position: 100% 50%;}
 100%{background-position: 0% 50%;}
}

h1{
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
       <title>Gradiendt Background</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
  </head> 

  <body>
       <h1>There is a gradient background.</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wonderful!Thanks for your explanation and the link makes me have better understanding.